# sql server 2008 email notifications

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have set up a profile and operator within SQL Server 2008. I also have an operator that is a group in MS Outlook.

When I use the single user address as the notification address when a job completes, the email is sent out (so profiles and mail is working). When i use the group address (its exactly the same format as the single user one - abc@abc.co.uk), nothing is sent out.

Any suggestions?

trobbie

Comment: Do you see any error messages when you run SELECT * FROM msdb.dbo.sysmail_event_log

Comment: hi, there is no error message - just "Database mail has started"

Comment: Did you confirm that if you send an e-mail manually to that account it gets received? Make sure to send from the same machine and through the same SMTP server.

Answer (score 1):

Have you created a contact group in Outlook or a Distribution group in Exchange? (I'm assuming you are using Exchange?)

The Outlook group is just a container that lets you send emails to many people from your personal machine.  The SQL Server is trying to send to a group that exists only on your Outlook and not on the Exchange server which is why single email recipients work but not the group.

I would suggest setting up, or asking your email admin to setup a new SQL support distribution group on your mail server.

or

You can send to multiple single email addresses by separating the address of the recipient with a ;